# generalized linear models two within-subjects factors

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures

I have two within-subjects factors A and B. Each participant undergoes all combinations of A and B. Now I am interested whether A or B or their combination can explain my DV (C) which is coded 0 and 1. So I create several  models, say:
1) C ~ A * B + (1|Subject)
2) C ~ A  + (1|Subject)
3)C ~ B + (1|Subject)
As 2) and 3) are not including all cases, do I have to aggregate for these models, or do I just include the same data as for model 1. In other words, do I have to create means across all levels of B for 2) and across all levels of A for 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your research question is whether `A`, `B` and/or their combination are associated with `C`, and all combinations were applied to each subject, it does not make sense to exclude either A or B from your model. An appropriate model is `C ~ A * B + (1|Subject)`, and the research questions can be answered with reference to the parameter estimates for `A`, `B` and their interaction: `A:B`